# Twitter intent and oauth

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth

I was googling and trying a lot with this issue but could not find a solution.

I have a micro site with Javascript. I want to do a "vote" for an awards, and the proceed is "make a tweet->get the user that tweeteed->thanks for voting username!".

I tried with twitter intent, but when I use the Intent Events for "tweet", the param "data" is empty, so I cannot retrieve the username.

Then, I tried creating a twitter ap, with keys and that. I added PHP for that, using different libraries, but the only thing I can achieve is allow to tweet but with the same account of the App, not with any account, as desired.

What I am doing wrong? I got lost.

Thanks a lot!